# CSS: Positioning not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put two boxes stack over each other in the bottom of another div. I have the following code:

```
<div style = "height:400px;width:400px;border:1px solid #000;">
    <div style = "position:relative;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000;bottom:0px;">
    </div>
    <div style = "position:relative;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000;bottom:0px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the boxes are in the top of their container not at the bottom. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the container relative, and the boxes absolute:

```
<div style = "height:400px;width:400px;border:1px solid #000; position:relative;">
<div style = "position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000;bottom:0px;">
</div>
<div style = "position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000;bottom:0px;">
</div>
```

EDIT FOR DEFINITVE ANSWER:

```
<div style = "height:400px;width:400px;border:1px solid #000; position: relative;">
    <div style = "position: absolute;height:100px;border:1px solid #000; bottom: 0;">
        <div style = "height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;"></div>
        <div style = "height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That puts the boxes over each other

Comment: @user1763032 That's what you asked for _stack over each other in the bottom_

Comment: Then position one of them higher:

    <div style = "height:400px;width:400px;border:1px solid #000; position:relative;">
    <div style = "position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000;bottom:100px;">
    </div>
    <div style = "position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000;bottom:0px;">
    </div>
</div>

Comment: @Wietse I do not know how many boxes there are going to be. so i cannot do that.

Comment: If you want them next to each other on the bottom, add another container: http://jsfiddle.net/jwxJj/

Comment: @Wietse Thank you.. That did it.. edit you answer and I will accept it.. Thank you very much

Comment: Edited for definitive answer, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

use bottom:0; in the second div, Then the first one in top another one in bottom

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.parent
{
    height:400px;width:400px;border:1px solid #000;
    position:relative;
}
.div1
{
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;border:1px solid #000;
}
.div2
{
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    bottom:0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your container needs position 'relative'

2) Your boxes need position 'absolute', not 'relative'

Answer (score 0):

The wrapping div should have a position:relative and the two internal divs should have position:absolute.

```
<div style = "height:400px;width:400px;border:1px solid #000; position:relative">
<div style = "position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000;bottom:0px;">
</div>
<div style = "position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000;bottom:0px;">
</div>
```

**[CSS-Tricks Video](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/110-quick-overview-of-css-position-values/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to add position relative to container div and absolute in child div. that bring the div in the bottom. avoid the overlapping both div change the bottom of the last div

```
<div style = "height:400px;width:400px;border:1px solid #000;position:relative;">
    <div style = "position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000;bottom:0px;">
    </div>
    <div style = "position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000;bottom:100px;">
    </div>
</div>
```